# Session_destroy() with max life time doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm trying to destroy the session after a while but it destroys directly I mean it's destroying when I pressed login. I think it means if condition doesn't work properly.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

include "baglanti.php";


session_start();

$user_check = $_SESSION['login_admin'];

$ses_sql = mysqli_query($baglanti,"select admin_username from admin where admin_username='$user_check' ");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$login_session = $row['admin_username'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['login_admin'])){

    header("location:.login.php");
}

    $inactive=100000;
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',$inactive);
    if(time() - $_SESSION['login_admin']>$inactive){

    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("location:.login.php");

    }
    $_SESSION["login_admin"]=time();
```

Comment: `if (time() - $_SESSION['login_admin']>$inactive)` is wrong. `$_SESSION['login_admin']>$inactive` returns a boolean (is the value in the session bigger than the value in $inactive), not a number. So you have the current timestamp minus true or false, (which will always return true, unless `time()` would return 0).

Comment: `$_SESSION['login_admin']` so how to get its value as timestamp?`$_SESSION['login_admin'].val()`?

Comment: The value already is a timestamp. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, since you're setting `$inactive` to 10000 (which is not a timestamp). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ı'm trying to achieve destroy session after a while depens on `$inactive`. I have already session_destroy function inside isset(logout button) and it works fine. But I also want to destroy session when currentTime-['login_admin']'s timeStamp > $inactive

Comment: Don't we set `$inactive` to a timestamp with `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',$inactive);` or do we have to assign this a variable?

Comment: And I will be appreciated if somebody ask. I know that sessions will be destroyed after 20mins or closed the browser. Is it true an any case? For instance in my code , I don't have to do anything to see that 20min and closing browser to destroy session, right?